# Not able to insert data into sqlserver, nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I have just made a simple program to display and insert data from a database(sql server 2008).  My code does the display of data.  I am unable to get data inserted.  It shows no error in terminal or browser.

```
Here is my javascriptfile
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/htm', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})
var sql = require("mssql");
var config = {
    user: 'pkp',
    password: 'pkp',
    server: 'PRAVEEN\\SQLEXPRESS', 
    database: 'myneww' 
 };
app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {

   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
   first_name:req.query.first_name,
   last_name:req.query.last_name
   };
 sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var request = new sql.Request();
    console.log(req.query.first_name);
    var res=request.query('insert into Mytab values(req.query.first_name ,req.query.last_name)');
    });
});

app.get('/alldata', function (req, res) {   
 sql.connect(config, function (err) {   
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from Mytab', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
});
});
 var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Here is my html file

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_get" method="GET">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to get the values displayed in the console, means values are passed and retrieved from the form.  But still not inserted into the database.

Comment: ` "insert into dabname(name,city) values(' "+name+" ',' "+city+" ')" `
That's it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good in javascript, but I guess the line below is incorrect:

```
var res=request.query('insert into Mytab values(req.query.first_name ,req.query.last_name)');
```

It should be something like this.

```
var res=request.query('insert into Mytab values(' + req.query.first_name + ',' + req.query.last_name +')');
```

If not, you've got an idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, you were not passing values properly to query and, secondly, you are not waiting for the record to insert. Add the callback that I added.

```
app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
   //some code
   sql.connect(config, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      var request = new sql.Request();
      console.log(req.query.first_name);
      request.query('insert into Mytab values('+req.query.first_name+','+req.query.last_name+')', function(err, recordset) {
           if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return res.send('Error occured');
           }
           return res.send('Successfully inserted');
       });
   });
});
```

**Update**

Use transaction to commit changes.

```
app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
   //some code
   var sqlConn = new sql.Connection(config);
   sqlConn.connect().then(function () {
      var transaction = new sql.Transaction(sqlConn);
      transaction.begin().then(function () {
         var request = new sql.Request(transaction);
         request.query('Insert into EmployeeInfo (firstName,secondName) values ('+req.query.first_name+','+req.query.last_name+')').then(function () {
            transaction.commit().then(function (recordSet) {
                console.log(recordSet);
                sqlConn.close();
                return res.send('Inserted successfully');
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Error in Transaction Commit " + err);
                sqlConn.close();
                return res.send('Error');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Forgive me, if there is any typo.

Comment: Hi, I tries as shown, no data inserted into table.. It shows an error res.send is not a function in terminal

Comment: try the updated code. earlier answer had typing error.

Comment: its shows successfully inserted in browser(but not).  In terminal shows some connection error: connection is closed.  But still when I give /alldata, I am getting the resultz..

Comment: can you share exact error stack trace ? Also, how many columns do you have in `Mytab` ? `insert into Mytab (firstName, lastName) values('parveen', 'krishna')`

Comment: piz find it here http://s31.postimg.org/qyvuy3p57/toupppp.png and this http://s32.postimg.org/w0tfnmibp/tonexx.png

Comment: The call to sql.Connection(config) needs to be changed to **sql.ConnectionPool(config)**.